# Automatically update the Application Setting using the binding from VS.Net Designer

Tags: c#

It's possible to [bind a property to an existing application setting using the designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yyxh69h.aspx), that way I don't have to write something like

```
textBox.Text = Settings.Default.Name;
```

when initializing my form.

Now it looks like the binding stops there, ie if I change the value of my setting, it won't update the value in my textbox and vice versa.

Is it normal or am I missing something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll explain how I do it on windows forms with Visual Studio 2010.  It is likely similar in newer versions.

1. Click on the component to bind (textbox, checkbox, ...)
2. Make component's properties panel visible
3. Expand the node `ApplicationSettings`
4. Click the `...` button to the right of `(PropertyBinding)`

   [image: Get application settings for component]
5. Choose which setting you want the control bound to.

There is a more detailed tutorial at [Exploring Secrets of Persistent Application Settings](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33944/0/page/3)

Comment: How do you save, I have found that if I update the textbox and close my app when I reopen it, the old value is still there?

Comment: I've tested that closing the app using the stop debug button the user settings aren't saved. You should close the app correctly ( red cross button ).

Comment: Is there any code I can manually call to persists the settings? For example on text Changed listener? or every 10 seconds?

Comment: Sadly the link you refer to now 404s.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle try again, it seems that it is working now

Comment: Thank you! From my understanding then, I have been able to bind the checkbox and string controls to the settings but not my combobox ones. They have to be done manually. My own question was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69247108/correct-way-to-bind-winform-controls-to-config-file-using-ide?noredirect=1#comment122392559_69247108. I will flag mine as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends.

First, I'm not sure if you're talking WPF or Windows Forms, so I'll assume neither.

Second, you are not "binding" anything.  You are taking the value of `Name` and setting the property `Text` equal to this value.  You are setting a property.  This does not come with any magic side-effects which inextricably links the `Name` property to the `Text` property.

Third, you can change settings, but until you save them, they are not written back to your app.config.  In a Windows Forms app, you'd have to do something like this:

```
// event handler for the Form.Closed event.
// this.FormClosed += FormClosed;
void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.Name = textBox.Text;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

In WPF, you'd use the normal binding semantics (which means you avoid the hassle of setting all the property values when closing), but you still have to trap for the form closing so you 
can Save() the settings.

Binding:

```
<TextBox 
  xmlns:lol="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Settings"
  Text="{Binding Name, Source={x:Static lol:Default}}" />
```

The Save() call happens much as with the Forms example, but you don't have to do anything other than call Save().

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here. I am *not* writing "textBox.Text = Settings.Default.Name;" thanks to the binding (see link).


I know that if I want the changes to be saved to the setting file, I have to specifically call "Settings.Default.Save();".