# x.Text not updating after assigning default value to it

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, telerik

I programmed in VS2013 using C#. I tried to modified a drop down textbox (Telerik RadDropDownListElement). Last user's input will be the default value when opening the software.

I used Properties.Settings.Default.var to save the user input. when I assign it to x.Text, I can no longer access the value in textbox entered by the user in run time.

```
public Initialize()
{ 
    /****other initial ****/
    x.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.var; 
    // set text to default value
}

private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.var = x.Text; 
    //x.Test still has the default value, not the value in textbox

    Properties.Settings.Default.save();
}
```

I tried to use property binding from following link, but I get similar result. 
[Automatically update the Application Setting using the binding from VS.Net Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371118/automatically-update-the-application-setting-using-the-binding-from-vs-net-desig)

How can I access the value in textbox instead of default value when I click save button?

/****edit detail****/
I can save x.Text to var if I comment out
`x.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.var;`
but then the default value is not shown.

I used drop down list as a simple textbox. Will this make a significant difference?
I'm not using index of drop down list, just the text.

Comment: do you have a class called `Properties.Settins` or is that just two typos in your question?  Did you type this in or cut/paste?  Are you verifying the value of x.Text in the debugger (wondering about your commented code), or from the assumption it is or is not getting saved to your Properties?

Comment: @KoryGill sorry for the typo. I typed this in, since the other computer doesnt have internet. I did verified the value of x.Text in the debugger.

Comment: I replace all my dropdownlist with textbox, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends how did you populate the drop down list. If it is in unbound mode and you have added the items manually, you could set the Text of the control, but if it is bound, you should work with Value.

However, I would suggest different approach. Instead of setting Text, set the SelectedItem (or SelectedIndex properties). To set the SelectedItem, find the item you need to select and assign it to the property:

```
radDropDownList1.SelectedItem = radDropDownList1.FindItemExact("your string", true);
```

Make sure the FindItemExact returns an item, if not, check your items and the saved string you have.

There are also couple other Find* methods you could use. They return index, that can be set in the SelectedIndex property.

Comment: The previous programmer use the drop down list as a textbox, so the drop down list is not popuplated at all (empty).  Will that make any difference?

Comment: In this case, this should be working just fine. You could either replace it with RadTextBox and see how it works, or you could upload a sample where the issue can be observed and I can have a look.

Comment: thanks! I just replace my radDropDownList with radTextBox, now it works. But your solution is pretty useful for my other parts of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Properties.Settings.Default["mysetting"];`

Comment: what do you meaning? replace all Properties.Settings.Default.var to  Properties.Settings.Default["mysetting"]? do I have to declare mysetting somewhere?

Comment: Look in the Properties directory of your solution. There should be a file there called Settings.settings. Open it, and start setting settings :)

Comment: I already set my Settings.settings. In my above code is "var" "string" "user"