# TextBox save value/input automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, text, while-loop

I would like to save a few values ​​from text boxes that should be loaded into the text boxes every time I restart my program.

However, since my customers all use different values ​​and should not re-enter them with every restart, I thought I could save these values ​​somehow.
But I have no idea how to do that.

my program is also tied to a database if there is a clean way, I would choose that too. my customers all have an account to log in to. but it can also be a simple .txt or XML file, but how does that work?

I working with visual Studio C# WinForms.

Comment: You can use the built-in [Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). You can tie a text box's value to one of those settings. [Automatically update the Application Setting using the binding from VS.Net Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047958)

Answer (score 3):

Windows Forms comes with [Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), which allow you to save variable values and load them back up the next time your program is run. The Designer allows you to create settings and set the data types for them. See the Microsoft documentation in the link above for more information.